# automatic generated forms ,workflows

Tags: java, struts2, owl

my question consists of 2 parts

1. if I have a bean could i automatically generate the form from it
2. if i have many beans , is it possible to automatically generate a workflow of the automatically generated forms from these beans

i need this  to generate form from ontology

Comment: by bean you mean the model/DTO or in short data carrying object?

Comment: These beans are generated from ontology files

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this using the [Play! framework](http://playframework.org) and [Empire](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire), which is an implementation of JPA 1 using SPARQL & triple stores in place of SQL & RDBMS.

I created Java beans annotated by Empire, which I can use to persist into my triple store, and combined with [Imperium](https://github.com/mhgrove/Imperium), the Empire plugin for Play!, I can use the Play! framework's built in CRUD form generation to create entry forms for my beans.

I wrote both Empire and Imperium, fwiw.  There are other frameworks for semantic web bean persistence, such as [Alibaba](http://openrdf.org), but none that I'm aware of that integrate nicely with JPA or a web framework such as Play! which will support the CRUD form generation automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You could try looking at Appfuse. You can watch a video demo of CRUD with Struts2 at http://demo.appfuse.org/ to see if it is going to be of use to you.